# Read standard deviation from graph

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I do not understand the statement below. I think it's an easy rule that I overlook. I understand how you read the average, but how do you determine the standard deviation?

The graphs all show the normal probability density function.

It is stated that graph 1 has an average of 10 and standard deviation 2.

[image]

Comment: From the peaks, assuming it's normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The function has the form $f(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\,e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$. The maximum of the curve is at $x=\mu$ and has the value $f(\mu) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$. In the picture you can read off $f(\mu)$. So you just have to solve for $\sigma$, which gives $\sigma = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}f(\mu)}\approx \frac{1}{2.5\cdot f(\mu)}$.

For example for graph no. 2 you have $f(\mu) = 0.4$, so $\sigma\approx\frac{1}{2.5\cdot 0.4}=1$.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I solve it while I don't know the function f(x)?

Comment: You know the *form* of the function. It is the same form for each of the graphs. Now, take one of those graphs. You can see what $\mu$ is -- it's the $x$-value at the maximum. And you can also see what the $y$-value is there, namely $f(\mu)$. So, you know $\mu$ and $f(\mu)$. In my answer I show how this yields $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a normal:

[image]

The height at a peak is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma}$$

The height at the point one standard deviation away from the peak is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma} e^{-1/2}$$

So find the point that is $e^{1/2} \approx .606$ the height of the peak.  The difference between its $x$ value and $\mu$ is $\sigma$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...